# Static field fails to initialize

Tags: c#, .net

I've simplified my question, since extension methods had nothing to do with it.

Here is the code snippet:

```
class MyClass
{
    private static readonly char[] InvalidChars = new []{'\\', '/'};


    public MyClass()
    {
        if (InvalidChars == null)
        {
             //how can this block be accessable? 
        }
    } 

}
```

My question is: is there any scenario in which InvalidChars can return null when it is accessed in MyClass constructor? Obviously there is, because that what i see in my application. Though i fail to understand hows that possible.

Comment: The code you've given doesn't throw the exception you've described. I've written a short but complete program which just called the `MyClass` constructor, and it's fine. Please edit your question to show code which demonstrates the problem, otherwise it's going to be impossible for us to diagnose.

Comment: Where / how do you instantiate `MyClass`? This doesn't seem an extension method at all.

Comment: Are you shure that "SomeName" is assigned to the Name Proeprty ?

I would assume that name is null nor invalidchars. Also Try setting a breakpoint and start the debugger

Comment: What extension method? The code you've posted is working as intended, if currently, isValid is true and when you change Name to "SomeName/", it is false. no exceptions. See demo: http://ideone.com/rz4R7e

Comment: I think you don't mean "Extension Method" but "Constructor"

Comment: @Haedrian (and others) - there *is* an extension method in there (`Any`), but I don't know why the OP has decided that it's part of the (not yet evident) problem.

Comment: @Mennan Kara: IEnumerable.Contains.

Comment: @Boas Enkler: Ofc i ve tried to debug this. Its the static field which is null, not the Name property

Comment: @Jon Skeet: you are right, i've just tried it and it does not. Thats really wierd. However the snippet is correct, and i fail to see how an outside code can somehow affect it and cause it to throw an exception.

Comment: @Nik - so you need to construct a *short* but *complete* example that actually demonstrates the problem - often, in the course of doing so, you'll work out what the issue is - but if not, we really need to see some code that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: How do you call the constructor? Simply `new MyClass()` or through reflection?

Comment: A few potential reasons for such an issue, but none of them applies to your specific code: 1) initializer throws an exception 2) circular dependencies 3) static constructor overwrites it 4) private reflection overwrites it.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: yea, i know. Its not worth the time atm tho. Still i thought that some1 might know the answer off the bat, so no harm in asking :)

Comment: Please post a program that actually exhibits the problem. Not some similar program without the problem. Your example program clearly runs without the field being `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ohoho, i'm sorry guys, i've found the issue after looking carefully through the call stack. You were right, my code example was not complete. Here is the complete version:

```
class MyClass
{
    private static readonly MyClass Default = new MyClass();
    private static readonly char[] InvalidChars = new []{'\\', '/'};


    public MyClass()
    {
        if (InvalidChars == null)
        {
         //how can this block be accessable? 
        }
    } 

}
```

No wonder i was getting a null.

Answer (score 0):

Since you have marked it as a static, the readonly variable can only be initialized in a static constructor of a class.

When the variable is initialized in the declaration, for example:

```
public readonly int y = 5;
```

For an instance field, in the instance constructors of the class that contains the field declaration, **or for a static field, in the static constructor of the class that contains the field declaration.** These are also the only contexts in which it is valid to pass a readonly field as an out or ref parameter.

Hence, when you remove the static keyword in the declaration you will be able to initialize the variable in the constructor.

Comment: Static constructor causes the same exception. If i set a break point there - i can see that it is siply never called. And yes, everything works fine if i make this field non static. But the question here is why, not how.